# Shell/Bash - equality check between strings returns 1 on match

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, command-line-interface

I'm trying to compare output of a cli command `"successful"` with simple `test = $?` but getting `1` even though values match. I did the same on hard-coded example and works fine.

Should the variable that stores cli's output be in different wrapping?

```
#ri status:
ri_status=`aws dms describe-connections --filter Name=replication-instance-arn,Values=$ri_arn --query=Connections[0].Status --region us-east-1`

#returns "successful"
echo $ri_status

#this returns 0
test "successful" = "successful"
echo $?

#this returns 1
test $ri_status = "successful"
echo $?
```

Comment: Might be a `\n` at the end of what the command returns?

Comment: Try `test "$ri_status" = "successful" `

Comment: Got `1` Paolo. Still, thanks 4 help!

Comment: Are you sure `$ri_status` is *exactly* "successful"? It may contain whitespace (which `echo $ri_status` will remove), nonprinting/invisible characters like carriage returns, etc. Try `declare -p ri_status | LC_ALL=C cat -v` and see if anything weird shows up.

Comment: Where to place above line? `declare -p ri_status | LC_ALL=C cat -v`

Comment: `Where to place above line?` Anywhere after assigning to `ri_status`. `declare -p ri_status` prints the value of variable `ri_status` in unambiguous way.

Comment: I got `declare -- ri_status="\"successful\""`

Comment: This fixed the issue: `test $ri_status = '"successful"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with `'`

http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting

> 3.1.2.2 Single Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal
> value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not
> occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

```
test $ri_status = '"successful"'
```